# success.php in my first contact form plugin results in page not found

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form, file-not-found

UPDATE:  sorry,  thanks for the solutions offered... not really clear how to implement, I think ive not been too clear... if I can understand how to implement the solutions thatd be neat...

Ive also successfully managed to get code working to create a new database table and insert test data  but ommited that so its not so complex....

I REALLY want to be able to...

- display some content that I can put in success.php (or else where) when the  message is sent successfully
  that content would say Message Sent - YAY! and then Id like to be able to add, exisiting wp content  - some services or products you might be interested in and display them on that same success result page after the message is sent...

maybe there is a better way to redirect users after the message is sent...

then....I also need to save the form data (not yet done) to the new table that I have created (got the table created via plugin), and then display a table of all form submission records in admin panel (not done)

- I replaced the content of my main.php file (the plugin's main php file in plugin-name root.

  ```
  <?php
  /** template info etc...
  **/
  // Find all .php files in the includes dir of my plug in folder. 
  foreach ( glob( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . "includes/*.php" ) as $file ) {
  include_once $file;
  } 
  ?>
  ```
- and all my files except the main one (which is in the plugin root) are in plugins/plugin-name/includes and are being found - YAY

so my includes/webform.php displays the form nicely it sends an email **but I can't get this error or success message via success.php or error.php thing to work.**

- includes/success.php now looks like this... as per DK's suggestion

  ```
  <?Php
  $Errors = implode(' ', $_SESSION['errMsg']);
  echo $Errors; ?>
  ```
- includes/webform.php now looks like this...

  ```
  <?php

  function d6s_opp_html_form() {
  echo '<form action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';

   //Form action page is the current url.  the form is called by a shortcode that will run functions that are written within this plugin's files, they can be in different files in different folders within the plug in because we have told the plug in to load them in the main plug in file.php horray thay is working..     

  // other form fields removed to shorten this stakoverflow post 
  echo '<p>';
  echo 'Your Name* <br />';
  echo '<input type="text" name="d6s-opp-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["d6s-opp-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["d6s-opp-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" placeholder="First & Last name" required />';

  // Now using required - is that better than having to check if not empty in success or fail bit????

   echo '<p><input type="submit" name="d6s-submitted" value="Send"/></p>';
   echo '</form>';
  }

  //Short code function is here and works GREAT
  ```
- Then  below that in the same file this is the function i figured DK meant that I should put the first part of his solution 1

**I Guess this is where I have it wrong still**

```
   function deliver_opp_mail() {
       // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
   if ( isset( $_POST['d6s-submitted'] ) ) {

    //sanitise form values so that form data is readable... eg/ if users enter code/script or formatting symbols, it is not missinterpretted as code and is seen as all text. 
    $name    = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["d6s-opp-name"] );
    $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST["d6s-opp-email"] );
    $messagesubject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST["d6s-opp-subject"] );
    $messagecontent = esc_textarea( $_POST["d6s-opp-message"] );
    $phone = ( $_POST["d6s-opp-phone"] );
                //  Would like to consider calling form values via global Variables. 

    $subject = "NEW OPPURTUNITY: $messagesubject";

    $d6sdir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

    //Create the Email Body Message using free text and data from the form.  
    $message = "New Message From: $name \n MESSAGE: $messagecontent \n Return Email: $email \n Return Phone $phone ";


    // get the blog administrator's email address, form data is emailed to this email address.  
    $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
            // Look into setting a to: Email address in WP Admin Console. 

    $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {

    //maybe this is in the wrong spot, or perhaps this is not the solution I need, but I have tried this in a few different places and can't get it to work.. 
        $Msg = array(
            "You have an error",
            "Your mail sent succesfully"
        );

        $_SESSION['errMsg'] = $Msg;

    //this take the user to www.mydomain.com/.....wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/includes/success.php - the file is there, but WP theme not found is displayed. 

 header("Location: $d6sdir/success.php");
exit;
   }
   }
   }
   ?>
```

*Dont want to display a message above the form on success or error... future plans for workflow need to take users to a page with no form and other content after they hit submit.

*also using error reporting - seems like something happen or flashes up before the not found from the theme bit is displayed and no other error are reported...

```
    <?Php  error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**************************  FROM INITAL POST....
Really keen to learn.   First post, thanks for help

**Purpose of plug in:** Create a plugin that I can eventually build into a custom CRM tool for my small business and Learn to code.

*Why is this so not simple...

Comment: Session is One of solution to pass errors or success to success.php and then display like so 
`if(isset($_SESSION['message']) AND !empty($_SESSION['message']) ): echo "<div class='alert danger'>".$_SESSION['message']."</div>"; endif;`

Comment: Actually that little bad idea to use independent file as redirect of form, but what you can do is just use same code and put conditional code based on `$_POST` just before form and put that message from `success.php` to this condition so message will be just before or after form as your want to show, let me know if this make sense, and this won't require any redirection

Comment: What is `echo plugin_dir_path(__DIR__)`? Or do you want a path a path based on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or WP install path instead?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** passing messages to `success.php`

```
$Msg = array(
    "You have an error",
    "Your mail sent succesfully"
);
$_SESSION['errMsg'] = $Msg;

success.php 

$Errors = implode(' ', $_SESSION['errMsg']);
echo $Errors;
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
$_SESSION["errMsg"] = "Your mail sent succesfully";

if(isset($_SESSION['errMsg']) AND !empty($_SESSION['errMsg']) ): 
echo "<div class='alert danger'>".$_SESSION['errMsg']."</div>"; 
endif;
```

**Not found solution :**

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to find root `D:/wamp/www`

and then full url to page like so :

`echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/yourFolder/test.php";`

output :`D:/wamp/www/yourFolder/test.php`

**Note** : will be nice if you use `exit();` right after `header("Location:");`